# UITableView in decoration purposes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift, profile

I am trying i am working on my social network app and I need to implement my profile settings window

To show what exactly I am talking about I will attach a picture.
https://pp.vk.me/c622224/v622224461/18d2f/lqcCCkXxHiY.jpg

I have 3 following questions:

1)Which kind of cells should be used (Static, Prototype, Dynamic) in order to create this kind of view.

2)How did they manage to resize 2 of 3 cells' width in order to fit an image there too

3)Are these gaps between different sections being a different table?

Comment: What makes you think that's even a table view? It could just be some text fields and image views.

Comment: @rdelmar I thought that as well, but that default separator style between text fields is a part of tableview as I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - You must use prototype cells in order to change the data for each user

2 - The photo section can be a UIView added as subview to UITable

3 - The gaps are not because of different tables, is a table setup as Grouped instead of Plain.

Comment: Clean and short answer! Thank you very much,wish I had rating to upvote